# Copying an ifstream to istream C++14

Tags: c++, io, c++14

I want to do something like this but keep running into an error, regarding the copy assignment operator for istream is protected. I want to have a way to switch input from cin to input from a file at some unknown point in my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   istream &in = cin;
   ifstream f{"file.txt"};
   in = f;
   // Then I want to read input from the file.
   string s;
   while(in >> s) {
     cout << s << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Streams are not assignable/copyable. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `in=f;`? This makes no sense. Just use `operator>>` on `f` directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "copy a stream". A stream is not a container; it is a flow of data.

What you appear to *really* be trying to do is to rebind a reference. Well, you can't do that either (there's literally no syntax for it, hence your compiler thinks you're trying to copy-assign the stream itself), so use a pointer instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   istream* in = &cin;
   ifstream f{"file.txt"};
   in = &f;
   // Now you can read input from the file.
   string s;
   while(*in >> s) {
     cout << s << endl;
   }
}
```

Make sure that `f` survives for as long as `in` is pointing to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by reassigning stream buffers with [`rdbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf):

```
in.rdbuf(f.rdbuf());
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3QWg1AbQScPHNCZ3)